# How to fill a form in a web page automatically

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm a new UNIX-Like system user and now I need to achieve such a function with script:

- open an url
- fill its form
- click the submit button

I don't want to use any software to do this job. What I need is just running a script and finishing the job.

Can you give me a simple example?
For example, how to code a script to use Google automatically to search a key word?

Comment: This question is (probably) off-topic on this site. Try using `curl` to send a `POST` request. Also see http://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request

Comment: Your question is off-topic on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/) because it does not show any code. You are confused. You should read a lot more about [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), [HTML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5), [POST requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29), [cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie). You might need some HTTP client command like `wget` or `curl`. You probably need to code something, using some HTTP client library like [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch No, [there is no universal code requirement on SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291399/4174897). The question just needs to be clear and focused. Here, however, the question is too broad.

Comment: Upvoted to balance out that downvote. I feel its a valid question, and understood - OP doesn't know where to start, never mind some initial code - we need to help folks that really want to learn (though I admit some more aggressive googling from OP would have given results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into cURL - you'll be able to post data to a URL / form action, something like:

`curl -X POST -F 'formfield1=somedata' -F 'anotherformfield=moredata' http://domain.com/aform.php`